# How to add more quotations in Laravel Inspire class?

Tags: laravel, vendor

How to add more quotations in Laravel Inspire class? As this file comes inside vendor folder and this folder is not beind uploaded directly on production.

I tried over the internet. I looking for an answer which is production ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-copy the inspiring class in the vendor anywhere in the app folder and add the quotes you prefer.

2-change the namespace accordingly

3-in the routes/console.php file add: use App\XXX\Inspiring; (replace XXX with the correct path) and delete use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;

run the command and it should work.

another approach could be to extend the original class.